# Perl Looping through an array by group

Tags: arrays, perl, csv, extract

I am a beginner in Perl. I usually work in Excel.
I have data which has been collected in csv format.
I am reading data from the first part of the file.
Coming to the main section of the file, I need to read data into groups being measurements taken.

The file looks like this, where column 1 has a ***variable number of lines per group***, and column 2 has a ***variable number of readings per grouping in column 1***.

I wish to read off the details in column 3 and additional columns based on the groupings in columns 1 and 2:

I have read the data into an array of arrays.

I am looking at something like this:

```
for(my $i =20; $i < *#variable length, how to set?* ; $i++){
print "$AoA[$i][0] $AoA[$i][3] $AoA[$i][4] \n";
next
```

I am sure, also, this isn't the only question that's going to arise with this project. I don't always understand what the various websites are saying. :)

```
   1;        1;P; 353 more columns...
   1;        2;P; 249 
   1;        3;P; 316 
   1;        4;P; 365 
   1;        5;P; 320 
   1;        6;P; 392 
   1;        7;P; 375 
   1;        8;P; 297 
   1;        9;P; 309 
   2;        1;P; 387 
   2;        2;P; 433 
   2;        3;P; 338 
   2;        4;P; 313 
   3;        1;P; 251 
   3;        2;P; 419 
   3;        3;P; 362 
   3;        4;P; 266 
   3;        5;P; 314 
   3;        6;P; 395 
   4;        1;P; 355 
   4;        2;P; 338 
   4;        3;P; 302 
   4;        4;P; 367 
   4;        5;P; 367
```

Full width of columns:

```
   1;        1;P   Pine; 353;   0;25.0;   0;  0.0; 1.27
   1;        2;P   Pine; 249;   0;23.0;   0;  0.0; 0.57
   1;        3;P   Pine; 316;   0;22.0;   0;  0.0; 0.87
   1;        4;P   Pine; 365;   0; 0.0;   0;  0.0; 0.00
   1;        5;P   Pine; 320;   0; 0.0;   0;  0.0; 0.00
   1;        6;P   Pine; 392;   0; 0.0;   0;  0.0; 0.00
   1;        7;P   Pine; 375;   0; 0.0;   0;  0.0; 0.00
   1;        8;P   Pine; 297;   0; 0.0;   0;  0.0; 0.00
   1;        9;P   Pine; 309;   0; 0.0;   0;  0.0; 0.00
   2;        1;P   Pine; 387;   0;23.8;   0;  0.0; 1.40
   2;        2;P   Pine; 433; 432; 0.0;   0;  0.0; 0.00
   2;        3;P   Pine; 338;   0;27.5;   0;  0.0; 1.23
   2;        4;P   Pine; 313;   0; 0.0;   0;  0.0; 0.00
   2;        5;P   Pine; 362;   0; 0.0;   0;  0.0; 0.00
   2;        6;P   Pine; 309;   0; 0.0;   0;  0.0; 0.00
   3;        1;P   Pine; 251;   0;20.3;   0;  0.0; 0.50
   3;        2;P   Pine; 419; 402;23.8;   0;  0.0; 1.57
   3;        3;P   Pine; 362;   0;23.4;   0;  0.0; 1.20
   3;        4;P   Pine; 266;   0; 0.0;   0;  0.0; 0.00
   3;        5;P   Pine; 314;   0; 0.0;   0;  0.0; 0.00
   3;        6;P   Pine; 395;   0; 0.0;   0;  0.0; 0.00
   3;        7;P   Pine; 339;   0; 0.0;   0;  0.0; 0.00
   4;        1;P   Pine; 355;   0;19.6;   0;  0.0; 0.97
   4;        2;P   Pine; 338;   0;19.2;   0;  0.0; 0.86
   4;        3;P   Pine; 302;   0;20.5;   0;  0.0; 0.73
   4;        4;P   Pine; 367;   0; 0.0;   0;  0.0; 0.00
   4;        5;P   Pine; 367;   0; 0.0;   0;  0.0; 0.00
   4;        6;P   Pine; 344;   0; 0.0;   0;  0.0; 0.00
```

Data::Dumper Sample output:

```
  [
    '1',
    '1',
    'P   Pine',
    353,
    '0',
    '25.0',
    '0',
    '0.0',
    '1.27'
  ],
  [
    '1',
    '2',
    'P   Pine',
    249,
    333,
    '23.0',
    '0',
    '0.0',
    '0.57'
  ],
  [
    '1',
    '3',
    'P   Pine',
    '316',
    '0',
    '22.0',
    '0',
    '0.0',
    '0.87'
  ],
```

Comment: Can you `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \@AoA;` so we can see what that array looks like?

Comment: And please also add example data that actually has some of those more columns.

Comment: @Sobriquet Supplied above.

Comment: @simbabque Supplied above.

Comment: "Read data into groups" -- and then what? How do you intend to use that data? That will determine the data structure you need. (Although, at first glance, it sounds like a job for hashes. Also, there's most likely no need for the intermediate array reference.)

Answer (score 0):

When you are iterating over an array it is better to use script style for loops rather then C style loops.  This will do the same thing as you want.

```
for my $array (@AoA[ 20 .. $#AOA]) {
   print $array->[0] . " " . $array->[3] . " " . $array->[4] . "\n";
}
```

In Perl $#ARRAYNAME is the largest index of @ARRAYNAME.

Comment: You might want to add a link to the relevant perldoc.

Comment: @Q the Platypus. Thank you for the 'Perl $#ARRAYNAME' reference.

Comment: @Q the Platypus. Thanks. Another thing learned. I now must get this output you kindly helped me with into groups based on column 1 and in sequences based on column 2 into a sprintf useable form.

Comment: @Q the Platypus I wonder if you could explain the $array->[] references.  
    I have tried to use them as  :  
      my $hghts = "$array2->[3]$array->[5]";  
but results are not what I expect, giving only the first value not them all. (Sorry didn't understand the formatting instructions)

Comment: If you have a reference to an array in $array then $array->[$index] will give you the value at $index in that array.

I suspect that the problem you are running into is by using "$array->[1]$array->[2]" inside double quotes.  With complicated code inside interpolating quotes you can get unexpected results.  So its safer to only use interpolation with simple variables and use concatenation in other cases.